# vba: define values in series using range with cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define the vales in a series using a range.

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(1002, col))
```

This however does not work. It fails with error 1004.

Answer (score 1):

The cells were not found. It works now with

```
Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(2, col), Sheets("Data").Cells(1002, col))
```